# Kilayim in Chutz la'eretz

Tags: halacha, chutz-laaretz, agriculture, kilayim-forbidden-mixture

What is the din with regards to kilei hayerek in chutz la'eretz? I see that many people have gardens in their backyards with vegetables right next to each other of different types.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18927/does-kelayim-apply-to-road-cantaloupe-courgette/18932#18932 
The answer says: 

The Rambam (Kilayim 1:3) and the Shulchan Aruch (YD 297:2) explicitly rule that the issue of Kilaei Zeraim (planting mixtures of edible seeds (except grapes)) only applies in the Land of Israel and a Jew can even plant his own mixtures outside of Israel on purpose. Is the rule on "seeds" the same as for vegetables?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok "seeds" is the catchall term for non-trees.

Comment: @DoubleAA [Is it](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=39b&format=text)?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin For our purposes, yes http://mechon-mamre.org/i/7101.htm#7 even if there are subcategories of "seeds". Be careful about using English terms for Halachik categories.

Answer (score 8):

The Rambam ([Kilayim 1:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=7&hilchos=34&perek=1&halocha=3&hilite=)) and the Shulchan Aruch ([YD 297:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=499)) explicitly rule that the issue of Kilaei Zeraim (planting mixtures of edible seeds (except grapes)) only applies in the Land of Israel and a Jew can even plant his own mixtures outside of Israel on purpose.