# Eating minneola’s kosher?

Tags: halacha, food, commentaries, fruits

The mixing of certain seeds isn’t allowed, does this also mean that fruits like minneola’s which are a mixture of grapefruits and tangarines aren’t kosher?

Comment: Here in Israel, I was served a fruit formed  from apple and pear seeds which I was assured is kosher.

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93467/in-what-way-are-hybrid-plants-trees-prohibited

Comment: Grapefruits are pomelo+mandarins, so it's already a mixture

Comment: @DoubleAA good point, I was just looking for an example, but this is true.

Answer (score 3):

The question was asked in [Hidabroot](https://www.hidabroot.org/article/1164666). The answer is:

> יש איסור להרכיב שני סוגי עצי פרי זה בזה, וכמו שכתב השלחן ערוך יורה דעה
> (סימן רצ"ה סעיף א') כלאי האילנות הרי הם בכלל מה שנאמר שדך לא תזרע
> כלאים, כיצד? המרכיב אילן באילן, כגון שהרכיב יחור של תפוח באתרוג או
> אתרוג בתפוח הרי זה לוקה מן התורה, בכל מקום - בין בארץ בין בחוץ לארץ.
>
> והתשובה היא - על אף שאסור לעשות כן, וכן אסור לקיים עצים אלו, הפרי
> היוצא מהם מותר באכילה, וכמו שכתב השלחן ערוך (שם סעיף ז') אסור לקיים
> המורכב כלאים, אבל הפרי היוצא ממנו מותר, ואפילו לזה שעבר והרכיבו. ע"ש
>
> It is forbidden to combine two types of fruit trees together, and as
> the Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah wrote (Simon 295, section 1), hybrids of
> trees are in general transgress the Torah's prohibition of sowing
> hybrids. How? Grafting an etrog into an apple is a violation of the
> Torah, everywhere - both in Israel and abroad.
>
> And the answer is - although it is forbidden to do so, and it is also
> forbidden to maintain these trees, the fruit that comes from them is
> allowed to be eaten, and as the Shulchan Aruch wrote (ibid., section
> 7) it is not allowed to maintain the compound as a hybrid, but the
> fruit that comes from it is permitted, and even for the one who
> transgressed and made the graft.

So we see that it is permitted to eat the produce of grafted trees.

Comment: This is THE answer. Thank you! An interesting, separate question -- what types of citrus are closely-enough related that they may be hybridized to begin with?

Comment: @Shalom All. Everything is a combination of citron pomelo and mandarin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrus_taxonomy