# When is a grafted tree Kosher?

Tags: time, fruits, kashrut-kosher

I understand that fruit isn't kosher if it is picked in the first 3 years of growth. However, what about grafting trees? If two branches come from trees that each more that 3 years old, but the grafted tree itself isn't 3 years old, is it Kosher? Then, what if one branch is more than 3 years old, but another is less than 3 years old? If a tree has grown for one, and then a branch is taken and grafted to anther tree, does the grower have to wait 3 years, or just 2?

Comment: [grafting is forbidden](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2826/5), btw, although that doesn't mean the fruit is not Kosher.

Answer (score 2):

See Mishnah Orlah 1:5 Raav Bartenurah where he says that if the branch was detached and then grafted, then we start counting the 3 years from when it was grafted. But if it was grafted in a way that it's still attached to it's original tree, then we don't start counting again.

Basically, once it's detached and replanted (translate grafted) the counting starts over.

Comment: So, if I have a red apple tree that is 5 years old, and I graft a green apple tree branch to said tree, then I could eat the red apples, but not the green apples?